# Does flagging a post as spam automatically down-votes it?

Tags: support, spam, flagging

I flagged some posts from the same user as spam, and I have noticed that all those posts have been down-voted.

Is that an automatic down-voted caused by flagging the posts as spam? If this is the case, does the automatic down-vote happen when just a user flags the post as spam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each spam flag counts as a -1 from the [Community](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile) user.